# Setting the range until last column in google sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that it will update the months every year. So let say if its 2021, it will automatically create 12 new columns from January 2021 until December 2021. I am doing a script in appscript so I want to know a way that it will automatically specify the range until last column. I have google about this thing but I can only find about finding the last row not the last column. So anyone here guys can let me know how to specify the range until last column. I have attached images and link to explain myself better. Thanks in advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=1775459006 - Link to my google sheet

[Google Sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVnPI.jpg)

Comment: To get last used column of one sheet, you can use getLastColumn() ... nevertheless, I don't understand that you want to fill columns with monthes. I think it is much more confortable and efficient to use pivot table directly from your paypal data sheets.

Comment: @MikeSteelson  Bro I am doing a web app using appscript bro. So the data will be linked to my google sheets. I cannot really use transpose function here because of the code I have done there bro. I provide you the link to google sheet and to web app, can you help to me to do this thing bro. I really appreciate it bro.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit?usp=sharing - Link to google sheets

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwjQU8ssIPe0Z_VBJyUzgn91Kd-i6Gftd73T-xWk9Gb8mtEybc9XG2_jFPLOKPapN5O/exec - Link to my web app

Comment: Username : JJACKSON
Password : PASSWORD1

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you want to get the last column of a sheet, then as Mike said that's just [`Sheet.getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) - is there a reason this isn't what you need?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Bro I am what this function to be edit in my appscript bro. In function **functionGetPaymentRecords(userProperties,filter)** I have set range from G:AD for  **var paidMonthValues** but I want it to be like G: last of column. I tried something but I coudnt solve it bro. Could you me on this thing? 

https://script.google.com/home/projects/1toEXTewITrSFNU_rDuSGkLfdH2_6ha-GTz5Q-McaNtlPIkoPaom4lrLo/edit - Link to appscript

Comment: `getRange(startRow, 7, noOfRows, sheet.getLastColumn() - 7)`

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Bro could you update in the link I have provided, please. Because I tried using that formula but its not working bro. So could you help me with it?

Comment: @MathavanKrishnan Sorry but no, questions and answers should be kept on-site so that future users can also see and solve their issues. If you can explain what the problem is with the snippet provided then maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Okay sorry bro. I have paste the code here. Can you help me now? Thank you so much.
`var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange("G:AD").getValues()`